# How can I add a message to Odoo inbox from an external system?

Tags: api, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-8, odoo-9

User adds a message to the external system (a bug tracker) that should call Odoo's web service API to create a message in Odoo inbox. The message contains an account name of the author (doesn't contain e-mail).

There are several questions related to this functionality.

What API method should be called by the external system?
How message's author can be identified as Odoo's contact?
Can a new contact be created if one isn't identified?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [API integration](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html) for this.

Message inbox it is **mail.message** object Odoo. 
You can find all fields of model here: *path_to_odoo/addons/mail/mail_message.py*.

You need to call method **create** using API. If you use Python it must be something like this:

```
id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'mail.message', 'create', [{
    'subject': "test",
    # other fields here...
}])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you clarify if `ext_username` field is added to `mail.message` model how can Odoo contact be created and linked to message? (`contact` model should contain `ext_username` field of course)

Comment: @tolyasik I have not worked with app `messaging`. But... Contact it is 'res.partner' object. You need just create a few records of **res.partner**  and after add new ids to field `partner_ids` of `mail.message`. I think it is will be work.

Comment: @tolyasik `partner_ids` it is **many2many** field. Be careful when using API. Exists 7 ways to work with the fields *One2many and Many2many*. You can read about this here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html. I think you need this command *(0, _, values)*. But I could be wrong.